# Let $T=D+N$ be $D-N$ decomposition, $E$ commutes with $T \iff E$ commutes with $D$ and $N$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T = D + N$ be the $D−N$ decomposition of a linear transformation $T \in L(V)$.  Prove that a linear transformation $E \in L(V)$ commutes with $T$ if and only if $E$ commutes with $D$ and $N$.

$D-N$ decomposition: Let $T \in L(V)$ & $V(F)$ contains all eigen values of $T$. Then there exist linear transformations $D$ and $N$ on $V$ such that, $T=D+N$ where $D$ is diagnolizable and $N$ is nilpotent.

If $E$ commutes with $D$ and $N$ then $E$ clearly commutes with $T$. However, if $E$ commutes with $T$, I don't understand how it commutes with $N$ and $D$. It is not necessary that a diagnol matrix commutes with every matrix. For example, $
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 \\
  \end{array} } \right) $
$
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right) \neq $
$
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right) $
$
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 \\
  \end{array} } \right) $.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re right that in general a diagonal matrix doesn’t compute with a nilpotent matrix.

However in the [$D-N$ décomposition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9composition_de_Dunford), **an important hypothesis is that... $D,N$ commute.**

In the proof of the [$D-N$ decomposition](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~gelineau/devagreg/Decomposition_Dunford.pdf), it can also be proven that $D,N$ can be written as polynomials of $T$. Then, if $E$ commutes with $T$, it is obvious that it commutes with $D,N$.

*Note: I refer above to French articles as I’m French and $D-N$ decomposition is named « décomposition de Dunford » in French. It seems that in English it is named [Jordan-Chevalley decomposition](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Yoo.pdf). The article provides an English proof of the arguments I mention above. See in particular proposition 4.1*